# What benefits can a character with no domains bestow with a wand of ceremony?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, crafting, magic-items

The 1st-level cleric spell [*ceremony*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/ceremony) is complex: first, the caster takes 8 hours casting the spell then for 1 hour grants 2 creatures a benefit depending on the picked ceremony—either funeral, holiday fete, marriage, or naming—*and* an additional benefit depending on one of the caster's domains.

Obviously, this is *supposed* to be a role-playing spell—like *AD&D*'s *Unearthed Arcana* spell *ceremony* that it echoes—, but this is *Pathfinder*, so Abe doesn't want to join two folks in holy matrimony<sup>1</sup> or name a baby<sup>2</sup> or any of that crap. He wants to use this spell to gain cheap water breathing or improve his monster-murdering ability.

Thus Abe, a spellcaster with the feat [Craft Wand](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/craft-wand-item-creation---final) who *can't* cast the spell *ceremony*, works alongside Bob, a cleric who *can* cast the spell *ceremony*, to [create](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Wands) a spiffy new *wand of ceremony* (1st-level spell at caster level 1) (750 gp; 0 lbs.) (50 charges).

The next morning—from, like, dawn until 2 PM—Abe makes a [Use Magic Device](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device) skill check to use the wand (DC 20) and takes 8 hours to cast on himself and his compsognathus familiar Clyde the spell *ceremony*.<sup>3</sup>

What domain benefits granted by the spell *ceremony* can Abe bestow on himself and Clyde? That is, is Abe limited in his choices because of the way the *wand of ceremony* was created? Further, must Abe make additional Use Magic Device skill checks to bestow these benefits because Abe doesn't have any domains?

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Granting the newly married couple for 1 hour a +1 sacred bonus on saving throws against fear and emotion effects. Sure. Whatever.
<sup>**2**</sup> Whose parents can can cast [*sanctuary*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sanctuary) once during the hour afterward. Maybe parent's'll need a 1-round time-out?
<sup>**3**</sup> C'mon, you *know* the ceremony Abe picks is holiday fete. The only other choice would see Abe and Clyde married, and Clyde's not ready, okay?

Answer (score 3):

While it's not RAW, I would argue that **Abe cannot use a domain ceremony unless he emulates one with a Use Magic Device check.** If Abe chooses to emulate a domain, he can pick any domain he meets the requirements for (or can emulate the requirements for), but must continue to emulate the domain throughout the entire casting of the *ceremony* spell. From the text of *ceremony*:

> In addition to these four ceremonies, each cleric gains two more ceremonies according to her domain.

This implies that since Abe doesn't have a domain, he does not gain the two additional ceremonies that a Cleric normally would. However, [Use Magic Device](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device) allows a practitioner to emulate a class feature, granting them the ability to activate an item as if they had that feature (but not being able to use that feature). Abe could choose to emulate a Cleric domain as a class feature (and select a different domain each time), and therefore would be able to use the additional ceremony provided by the chosen domain.

Use Magic Device also says:

> If you are using the check to emulate an alignment or some other quality in an ongoing manner, you need to make the relevant Use Magic Device check once per hour.

It takes 8 hours to cast the spell *ceremony*. Therefore, **Abe would need to succeed on 9 DC 20 Use Magic Device checks: eight to to emulate the Cleric domain class feature for the duration *and* another to activate the wand.**

One might say that the wand would be tied to Bob's domains, but I don't think that's the case because the ceremony performed is selected when the spell is cast and can be different with each casting of the spell. Even without a domain, Abe could select from *any* of the 4 available ceremonies every time he uses the wand. In essence, performing the ceremony and casting the spell are two different actions that occur at the same time. Therefore, Bob's domains are not transferred into the wand when it is made - having the domains represents knowledge of how to perform the ceremony in question.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer *ceremony* cannot be made into a potion because it has a casting time greater than 1 minute.

Comment: Where's *that* limit on potion brewing? Can you provide a link? (A *potion of ceremony* remains problematic, though, 'cause [it usually targets at least two people](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56761/8610). To whom is the drinker of a *potion of marriage ceremony* married?)

Comment: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/potions "It can duplicate the effect of a spell of up to 3rd level that has a **casting time of less than 1 minute** and targets one or more creatures or objects."

Comment: Thank you. I was *totally* unaware of that; I've never even read *mention* of that rule. Seriously, that's not in the feat [Brew Potion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/brew-potion-item-creation---final) nor in [Creating Potions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Potions) but in the *description* of potions. Sigh. *Pathfinder.*

Comment: Does anything change with this line from [Casting Time](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Casting-Time): "You make all pertinent decisions about a spell (range, target, area, effect, version, and so forth) when the spell comes into effect"? That is, could one just make the decision about what domain—and, therefore, just one Use Magic Device skill check—at the end of the casting?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I would say no, because the ceremony performed is different depending on the domain you choose. A wedding doesn't have the same ceremony process as a funeral, so why would it suddenly change its effect at the end of the procedure? Part of casting the spell is in performing the rites that grant the effect, so the caster would need continual knowledge of the domain they're using a ceremony from.

Comment: But for a *wand of ceremony*, "No gestures or spell finishing is needed, just a special knowledge of spellcasting that an appropriate character would know [i.e. the spell on the dude's spell list], and a single word that must be spoken." So while it still takes 8 hours to cast, it's just 8 hours of saying that one word instead of performing the for-reals ceremony. (I'm not hassling you, by the way; I just want to make sure all the bases are covered.)