# Can you brew a potion with "you" as a target?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, potions

The [Brew Potion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/brew-potion-item-creation---final) feat states that:

> You can create a potion of any 3rd-level or lower spell that you know and that targets one or more creatures or objects.

Does that includes spells with a *personal* range and *you* as the target, like for example [Alter Self](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/alter-self)? Technically it targets "one creature" (you), but at the same time it's not exactly written "one creature" so I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Brew Potion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/brew-potion-item-creation---final) feat allows a potion to be brewed of a spell that has an entry of *Target: You*, but *not* a potion of a spell that has an entry of *Range: Personal*. [Creating Potions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Potions) says pretty much exactly that: "Spells with a range of personal cannot be made into potions." Further, the description of [Potions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/potions) limits potions even more: A potion "can [only] duplicate the effect of a spell of up to 3rd level that has a casting time of less than 1 minute and targets one or more creatures or objects." Why all these rules aren't in one place is a mystery.

Thus it's typically impossible to brew, for example, a *potion of [alter self](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/alter-self)*.

Comment: I missed that "Spells with a range of personal cannot be made into potions." part. Deleted my wrong answer. Was it like this from the beginning, or was it errated?

Comment: @Mołot It's been that way since *3.5e*, but it's always been buried in Creating Potions, making it *really easy* to overlook. And I didn't know about long-casting-time spells being prohibited until, like, a year ago when I asked [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56761/8610).

Comment: I guess my *house-rule-believed-to-be-rule* that such potions works, but only on a brewer, just like Potion of Shillelagh works only on oak clubs, wasn't game-breaking. But glad to know what the real rules are.

Comment: Yeah, potions are pretty underpowered as a whole, especially if it costs you a feat to make them. My group plays that any non-gamebreaking spell can be made into a potion.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should add the following to this answer: "There's a *really* strict possible reading of the concept that a potion can duplicate only spells that target one or more creatures that excludes potions of spells that have *Target: You* and, instead, limits potions to spells with entries like *Target: One creature* and the like (*you* being different from, for example, *one creature* in a spell's target entry). I've never heard of a DM limiting potions in such a way (likely because potions usually suck), but it *is* a possible reading." Has anyone met a DM who ruled this way?

Comment: The "no personal" rule seems to be part of the general caster bias in PF. Many martial classes would benefit so much from being able to use all the personal-only spells but they remain firmly walled off to casters except by certain wondrous items. Instead wizard can get a great buff with a scroll of Shield but a fighter can't (legally) follow suit with a potion of Shield.

Comment: @TREB I agree, but it may go even deeper. The *no* Range: Personal *spell potions* thing dates back to *D&D 3e*, which, if memory serves, was extensively—yet not destructively—playtested *only* for levels 1–6, the range at which surveys at the time showed most games took place. At those levels (and, presumably, during those playtests), a core fighter outperforms a poorly (or, *a la AD&D 2e*, a  *traditionally*) played caster. I suspect that maybe removing potions of, like, *divine favor*, *shield*, *alter self*, and *false life* was to make such classes *less* attractive to power gamers!